# Why is dplyr's filter not working with white spaces in simple filter?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm new to learning R, and I'm trying to explore a dataset provided by the R for Data Science online community for movies - https://github.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/blob/master/data/2018/2018-10-23/movie_profit.csv.

As I'm going through and learning more about the filter function of dplyr, I noticed that I do not get any results when I search for a value within the "distributor" column with a white space in it - like "Walt Disney" in the example below. Searching for values that do not have a white space works just fine, like "Universal".

Also, I've tried with other columns in the dataset, like "movies" where I filter for a specific movie that has white-spaces in it; however, when I do that I run into no issues so I'm a bit puzzled.

```
library(tidyverse)

movies <- read_csv(url("https://github.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/raw/master/data/2018/2018-10-23/movie_profit.csv")) 

test <- "20th Century Fox"

movies %>%
  filter(movie == "Dawn of the Planet of the Apes") %>%
  View()
```

In short, I'd love to know the why behind this so that I know how to handle this if it comes up again in any future datasets that I explore. **The code that is giving me trouble is below.** **I want to plot the genre distribution of movies from the distributor "Walt Disney".**

```
movies <- read_csv(url("https://github.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/raw/master/data/2018/2018-10-23/movie_profit.csv")) 

test <- "20th Century Fox"

movies %>%
  filter(distributor == "Walt Disney") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = genre)) +
  geom_bar()
```

Comment: When I read the movie_profit dataset, for some reason I get special characters in  "WaltÂ Disney". This explains why == "Walt Disney" doesn't work

Comment: I was going to suggest something similar to the code in the answer. That error is weird to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in other posts, you have special characters instead of normal spaces in your tables. You can replace them with regular spaces and your code should work as normal, without having to manually copy the strings. I have added `trimws` to remove any trailing whitespace. Note that this also removes other special characters.

```
library(tidyverse)

movies <- read_csv(url("https://github.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/raw/master/data/2018/2018-10-23/movie_profit.csv")) 

# this line replaces non-alphanumeric characters with a space and removes any trailing whitespace at the end. 
movies$distributor <- trimws(gsub("[^[:alnum:]]", " ", movies$distributor))
movies %>%
  filter(distributor == "Walt Disney") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = genre)) +
  geom_bar()
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems to a mismatch in the string

```
all.equal("Walt Disney", "Walt Disney" )
#[1] "1 string mismatch"
```

If we check the values

```
unique(movies$distributor)[3]
#[1] "Walt Disney"

charToRaw(unique(movies$distributor)[3])
#[1] 57 61 6c 74 c2 a0 44 69 73 6e 65 79
charToRaw("Wald Disney")
#[1] 57 61 6c 64 20 44 69 73 6e 65 79
```

There is some difference triggered the mismatch

It is better to copy from the value in 'distributor

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
movies %>%
    filter(str_detect(distributor, "Walt\\s+Disney")) %>%
   count(genre) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = genre, y = n)) +
       geom_col()
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thank you @akrun, but I just copied and pasted the value from distributor, and tried your code and did not get the output you shared.

I'm getting a blank output for my plot.

Comment: @futureRwizard it is because I copied it directly from the `movies$distributor` value.  the space in `Walt Disney` is a little differnt.  You can use a regex with `str_detect`

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. This makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

The following uses `agrepl` for an approximate string match and it gives the graph in [akrun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62236647/8245406).

```
movies %>% 
  filter(agrepl("Walt Disney", distributor)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = genre)) +
  geom_bar()
```